# how to convert rosrun mux command to a launch file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a written several launch files that work.  But the format of topic_tools mux with its list of unnamed arguments baffles me.
I can make things work with

rosrun topic_tools mux sel_cmdvel joystick/cmd_vel cmd_vel mux:=mux_cmdvel

How can I put this in a launch file? like the following which doesn't work.

```
<launch>
 <!-- mux_cmdvel installation -->
 <node pkg="topic_tools" type="mux" name="mux_cmdvel" args="sel_cmdvel joystick/cmd_vel cmd_vel">
 </node>
</launch>
```

In response to Dornhege's request below, I add the following clarification which may or may not help.

I have a launch file which launchs 2 nodes which compute a joystick cmd_vel called “LeafJS/cmd_vel” and another node, leaf_base, which is a base controller and expects an input topic called sel_cmd_vel.   I am using mux to subscribe to the LeafJS/cmd_vel topic and output the sel_cmd_vel topic.  Of course the robot’s wheels do not respond to joystick commands at this point since mux isn’t running.

After running `rosrun topic_tools mux sel_cmd_vel LeafJS/cmd_vel cmd_vel mux:=mux_cmdvel`, the robot runs with mux selecting the default input `LeafJS/cmd_vel` and outputing `sel_cmd_vel` to the base controller which drives the wheels.  So, the mux is apparently working.

Now, the plot thickens…I run `rosnode info mux_cmdvel` as you requested and get

```
alex@rocky:~$ rosnode info mux_cmdvel
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node [/mux_cmdvel]
Publications: None

Subscriptions: None

Services: None

cannot contact [/mux_cmdvel]: unknown node
```

So, I look at rqt_graph which indicates that the mux node is actually called `sel_cmd_vel_mux_1380399404626786209`

If I rosnode info this node, I get:

```
alex@rocky:~$ rosnode info sel_cmd_vel_mux_1380399404626786209
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node [/sel_cmd_vel_mux_1380399404626786209]
Publications: 
 * /mux_cmdvel/selected [std_msgs/String]
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]
 * /sel_cmd_vel [geometry_msgs/Twist]

Subscriptions: 
 * /LeafJS/cmd_vel [geometry_msgs/Twist]
 * /cmd_vel [unknown type]

Services: 
 * /mux_cmdvel/delete
 * /mux_cmdvel/list
 * /mux_cmdvel/add
 * /sel_cmd_vel_select
 * /sel_cmd_vel_mux_1380399404626786209/set_logger_level
 * /sel_cmd_vel_mux_1380399404626786209/get_loggers
 * /mux_cmdvel/select


contacting node http://rocky:49171/ ...
Pid: 4008
Connections:
 * topic: /rosout
    * to: /rosout
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /sel_cmd_vel
    * to: /leaf_base
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /sel_cmd_vel
    * to: /rostopic_4120_1380399530443
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /LeafJS/cmd_vel
    * to: /leaf_teleop_joystick (http://rocky:44908/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
```

My rosrun mux… command seems just like the example in the wiki, so I don’t see why it has the long name rather than the simple assignment to mux_cmdvel.  But, it is working.

If I do run the mux launch file above,  I do get a mux_cmdvel node with the following info:

```
alex@rocky:~$ rosnode info mux_cmdvel
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node [/mux_cmdvel]
Publications: 
 * /mux_cmdvel/selected [std_msgs/String]
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]

Subscriptions: 
 * /cmd_vel [unknown type]

Services: 
 * /mux_cmdvel/set_logger_level
 * /mux_cmdvel/delete
 * /mux_cmdvel/list
 * /mux_cmdvel/add
 * /LeafJS/cmd_vel_select
 * /mux_cmdvel/select
 * /mux_cmdvel/get_loggers


contacting node http://rocky:44309/ ...
Pid: 4684
Connections:
 * topic: /rosout
    * to: /rosout
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: TCPROS
```

which seems to indicate it is launching some kind of default mux with the specified name, but not setting it up per the arguments.  So my question remains, how do I specify the arguments so that the mux node is using LeafJS/cmd_vel and cmd_vel as input sources and outputting  sel_cmd_vel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84386/how-to-convert-rosrun-mux-command-to-a-launch-file/) by [Alex Brown](https://answers.ros.org/users/125/alex-brown/) on ROS Answers with karma: 176 on 2013-09-27

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-28**:
"doesn't work." - what does that mean?

**Comment by [Alex Brown](https://answers.ros.org/users/125/alex-brown/) on 2013-09-28**:
It launches the mux node, but doesn't use any of the args.  It does not create a selected output of sel_cmdvel and doesn't subscribe to the two inputs; joystick/cmd_vel and cmd_vel.  I suspect the args have to be specified differently.  rqt_graph just shows the mux node alone with no connections

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-28**:
What do you get for `rosnode info mux_cmdvel`?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-30**:
Maybe one thing: The mux:=mux_cmdvel should go as a remapping in the launch file.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-30**:
This doesn't answer the question, but might be a better solution to what you want to do: Check out the cmd_vel_mux: http://wiki.ros.org/cmd_vel_mux  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got the launch file working this weekend.  Dornhege pointed out the missing item this morning.  When I wrote the question, I was assuming the "name="mux_cmdvel" item was redundant on the "mux:=mux_cmdvel". Apparently they don't do the same thing.
So, the real answer to my question is that placing all of the rosrun arguments in an "args=" item is proper formatting for a launch statement(which I wasn't sure of).  I was just missing the mux:= part.
Thanks

---

Originally posted by [Alex Brown](https://answers.ros.org/users/125/alex-brown/) with karma: 176 on 2013-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sakshi19K](https://answers.ros.org/users/36753/sakshi19k/) on 2018-11-29**:
Hi, I am facing the same issue..
can you please explain how you solved it?

**Comment by [hansolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/29473/hansolo/) on 2021-02-12**:
This should work: `<node pkg="topic_tools" type="mux" name="mux_cmdvel" args="sel_cmdvel joystick/cmd_vel cmd_vel mux:=mux_cmdvel">`